# how to display data from a textile - tkinter

Tags: python, file, tkinter, label

I have created the following code to create a leaderboard:

{data} {data} {data} {data} {data}

Any idea on how get each piece of data on a new line like below?

```
{data}
{data}
{data}
{data}
{data}
```

I am using a Label to display the data.

Thanks x

Comment: Please update your code to include some static data. Also, the indentation of the code is broken. I also don't see. how it's possible for you to get the output. you say you do, since you're placing every label at the same location.

Comment: @BryanOakley any ideas on how to change the labels location in the for loop? thanks

Comment: @BryanOakley, it is printing the list details along the screen, however I want to print it down the screen x

Comment: Please update the code in your question so we can reproduce your problem. Though, my gut reaction is to say not use use `place`. `pack` makes it trivial to stack widgets vertically.